# alternative to admin rights - fopen doesn't create C:\temp.txt in windows

Tags: c, qt, file-permissions, fopen, access-denied

In my current project I like to use `fopen` or `fopen_s` to create a file via "w" option.

Using a QT GUI the user may choose any file name which is basically the return string of a file dialog - similar to what is known to windows dialogs.

```
QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save as...","","all files (*.*)");
```

However, depending on the file name it gets created or not.

So for instance I can write files in my build directory 'C:/SVN/builds/GUI/temp.txt'

And I can create files on the windows desktop 'C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/temp.txt'

I can even create files in other build dirs 'C:/SVN/builds/foo/bin/Release/temp.txt'

But `fopen` doesn't let me create 'C:/temp.txt' and returns "access denied" (`errorno 13`)

my issue can be solved like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735652/2220850

but this effectively requires the user to have admin rights for my silly little tool to run properly.

so isn't there another way to get permissions to write the file the user selected from within the GUI?

Or is there at least for the user and me a way to know where on the disks our tool may or may not create files?

cheers

Comment: There are Shell API's to find out where to put stuff.

Comment: MSDN for  'KNOWNFOLDERID' and 'CSIDL'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve this in a clean way. There are folders that are forbidden to non-admin users. That's the way it is (without tweaking to OS settings).

Displaying your users a sensible error message like "Access denied (you may need admin rights to write to this directory, select a directory you may write to)" is probably the best way.

Comment: There are shell calls specifically to generate paths to folders with the desired attributes.

Comment: Which wouldn't solve the C:/temp.txt problem, would it? Also this is neither cross-platform nor Qt. Anyway, maybe your suggestion helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Read/write stuff where the shell/OS tells you you can/should do.  Call the shell API to find out the correct path for Windows OS:

```
SHGetFolderPath()
SHGetKnownFolderPath()
```